# Conditionally Replace Variable in a Calculation

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code which calculates the time in minutes between two time points - 'CompleteDataTime' and 'RequestedDateTime'.

```
 Select [Financial Number],
 datediff(mi,CompletedDateTime1, RequestedDateTime2) as Prov_to_dispo1
 FROM NewTable
 order by [Financial Number]
```

There are some records where the 'CompleteDataTime' variable is blank or missing; and therefore the code produces a 'null' value for these records when calculating Prov_to_dispo1.

I have another variable in my dataset 'Depart Date & Time', that I would like to use as a proxy for 'CompleteDataTime' when 'CompleteDataTime' is missing-is this possible?

I assume I need an IF-THEN statement that would look like

```
IF 'CompleteDataTime' = . THEN Prov_to_dispo1 = datediff(mi,'Depart Date & 
Time', RequestedDateTime2) as Prov_to_dispo1
```

The desired output should look like

```
 FIN  Prov_to_dispo1
  1        345
  2        685
  3        148
  4        306
  5        265
```

Comment: Assuming `CompleteDateTime` is `NULL` for some records, why not use `ISNULL(CompletedDateTime1,Depart Date & Time)` inside the `datediff` function? If they are in fact `blank`, then you could use a `CASE Statement`. `Prov_to_dispo1 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(CompleteDateTime,'') = '' THEN datediff(mi,'Depart Date & Time', RequestedDateTime2) ELSE datediff(mi,CompletedDateTime1, RequestedDateTime2) END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ISDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. According to official docs:

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, I would encourage you to use [`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) function instead of `CASE-WHEN` statement. If you don't know how `IIF()` function works, the syntax of `IIF()` function is like the following:

```
IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
```

Therefore, the code will be the following:

```
SELECT
  [Financial Number],
  DATEDIFF(
    mi,
    IIF(
      ISDATE(CompletedDateTime1) = 1, --boolean_expression
      CompletedDateTime1, -- true_value
      'Depart Date & Time' -- false_value
    ),
    RequestedDateTime2
  ) as Prov_to_dispo1
FROM NewTable
ORDER BY [Financial Number]
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
Select [Financial Number],
case when isnull(CompletedDateTime1, '') = '' then
    datediff(mi,DepartDateTime, RequestedDateTime2) 
else
    datediff(mi,CompletedDateTime1, RequestedDateTime2)
end as Prov_to_dispo1
FROM NewTable
order by [Financial Number]
```

Comment: using `ISNULL()` would be more appropriate here than using `COALESCE()`

Comment: @AdnanSharif Thank you for that tip. I edited my answer.